# Choose template function based on existence of member

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Let's say you have these two classes:

```
class A
{
 public:
     int a;
     int b;
}

class B
{
 public:
     int a;
     int b;
}

class C
{
 public:
     float a1;
     float b1;
}

enum class Side { A, B };
```

I want a template function which takes a `side` and a `T`, and depending on the `T`, returns a reference to "`T.a`" or "`T.b`" if the class has a member `T::a`, or a reference to "`T.a1`" or "`T.b1`" if the class has a member `T::a1`.

My starting point is:

```
template<typename T>
auto &GetBySide(const Side &side, const T &twoSided) 
{ 
  return side == Side::A?twoSided.a:twoSided.b; 
}

template<typename T>
auto &GetBySide(const Side &side, const T &twoSided) 
{ 
  return side == Side::A?twoSided.a1:twoSided.b1; 
}
```

The question is how to get the compiler to skip the first template if the member `a` does not exist.

So I implemented the solution given by @Jarod42 below, but it gave errors in VS 2015 because of a bug in VS ability to differentiate between templates. Here is a work around:

```
template<typename T>
auto GetBySide(const Side &side, const T& twoSided) 
-> decltype((twoSided.a))
{ 
  return side == Side::A ? twoSided.a : twoSided.b; 
}

// Using comma operator to trick compiler so it doesn't think that this is the same as above
template<typename T>
auto GetBySide(const Side &side, const T &twoSided) 
-> decltype((0, twoSided.a1))
{ 
  return side == Side::A ? twoSided.a1 : twoSided.b1; 
}

// See comment above
template<typename T>
auto GetBySide(const Side &side, const T &twoSided) 
-> decltype((0, 0, twoSided.a2))
{ 
  return side == Side::A ? twoSided.a2 : twoSided.b2; 
}
```

Another way would be to use the comma operator and a special struct which represented each "concept"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With SFINAE.

```
template<typename T>
auto GetBySide(const Side &side, const T& twoSided) 
-> decltype((twoSided.a))
{ 
  return side == Side::A ? twoSided.a : twoSided.b; 
}

template<typename T>
auto GetBySide(const Side &side, const T &twoSided) 
-> decltype((twoSided.a1))
{ 
  return side == Side::A ? twoSided.a1 : twoSided.b1; 
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb2fdd1beb7c31f9)

Comment: That's one of the ways that I tried, but I've been getting an error from Visual Studio stating that the function template has already been defined.

Comment: @Jarod42 The day in which you realize that `auto f() -> decltype((expr))` returns a reference (and you say - _that's obvious, how it happened that I've never thought at it before?_). Good catch. +1

Comment: @skypjack - actually it doesn't return a reference. I fell in that hole. To return a reference you'd need:
auto f() -> decltype(expr) &

Comment: @Jarod42 - Curious as to why you used decltype((twoSided.a)) instead of decltype(twoSided.a)

Comment: @bpeikes: Look at my demo, I explicitly add a `static_assert` for the return type. So extra parenthesis `decltype((twoSided.a))` make it *parenthesized class member access* (so returns reference) whereas `decltype(twoSided.a)` returns the member type (see [decltype doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)). But I agree that it is tricky.

Comment: I'll have to test that in Visual Studio, though I think I'll stick with auto f() -> decltype(expr) &.  I think adding the & makes it more clear.

Comment: You will have to add `const` : `const decltype(T::a) &`.