# C++ member overloads based on existence of template member

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have been starting with some SFINAE, but I can't quite get a handle on some of the cases that I want to use it for.

For example if I have a template based class which should have different implementations of a function depending on the template parameter i.e.

```
template <typename T>
class cExampleClass
{
     /// Function enabled when "cExampleClass::member" exists
     auto overloadedFunction() -> decltype((std::declval<t>().member()),T::some_dependant_type())
     {
           // Do some stuff and use cExampleClass::member
     }

     /// Function enabled when "cExampleClass::member" does not exist
     auto overloadedFunction() -> T::some_dependant_type()
     {
           // Do some different stuff
     }
};
```

where it would be ideal to just call the function as

```
object.overloadedFunction();
```

My compiler throws

> error: ‘class cARD’ has no member named ‘member’

on the decltype line (even when the fall back function is not defined). This seems to contradict the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811817/choose-template-function-based-on-existence-of-member), so what is the correct way to define the trailing return type?

Also, the function apparently cannot be overloaded. Is there an easy way to define a fallback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an hard error as your method is not template, change it to:

```
template <typename U>
class cExampleClass
{
     /// Function enabled when "cExampleClass::member" exists
     template <typename T = U>
     auto overloadedFunction()
     -> decltype((std::declval<T>().member()),T::some_dependant_type())
     {
           // Do some stuff and use cExampleClass::member
     }

     /// Function enabled when "cExampleClass::member" does not exist
     template <typename T = U>
     auto overloadedFunction() -> decltype(T::some_dependant_type())
     {
           // Do some different stuff
     }
};
```

but then you have issue as the method would be ambiguous for type which match both condition.

Adding tag to sort overloads is a possibility:

```
template <std::size_t I>
struct overload_tag : overload_tag<I - 1> {};

template <>
struct overload_tag<0> {};
```

and then

```
template <typename U>
class cExampleClass
{
private:
     /// Function enabled when "cExampleClass::member" exists
     /// Preferred function
     template <typename T = U>
     auto overloadedFunction(overload_tag<1>)
     -> decltype((std::declval<T>().member()),T::some_dependant_type())
     {
           // Do some stuff and use cExampleClass::member
     }

     /// Function enabled when "cExampleClass::member" does not exist
     template <typename T = U>
     auto overloadedFunction(overload_tag<0>) -> decltype(T::some_dependant_type())
     {
           // Do some different stuff
     }
public:
     template <typename T = U>
     auto overloadedFunction() -> decltype(overloadedFunction(overload_tag<1>{}))
     {
          return overloadedFunction(overload_tag<1>{});
     }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Especially with the tags.